# Geometric Progressions: Sum to Infitity

Tags: sequences-and-series

Good evening, would anyone be able to help with the question reading:

Find the sum to infinity of the geometric series:
$$ 3 + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{16} + \cdots $$
Find also the sum of the first n terms of this series. Show that however large $n$ may be, the sum cannot exceed $4$.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the topic of Progressions as I'm studying it at school, any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: The end result is that for $|x|<1$ we have $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$.  This is proven in a variety of ways depending on your preferences and skill level.  Here, you have your series is $3$ times the geometric series where $x=\frac{1}{4}$ and so the sum is...

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you see ratio is 1/4 and first term=3 so using formula a/(1-r) where a=first term r=ratio you have the sum is 3/(1-1/4)=3/(3/4)=4. So the infinite sum is 4, and because it is always increasing, the first n terms can't go over 4. So formula for sum of first n terms is S_n=(a(1-r^n))/(1-r) where a is first term r=ratio and S_n is sum of first n terms so stated before a=3 and r=1/4 so S_n=(3(1-(1/4)^n)/(1-1/4)=(3(1-(1/4)^n))/(3/4)=4(1-(1/4)^n).

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If $ (v_n)$ is a geometric sequence, then there is a constant $ q$, such that

$$(\forall n\ge 0)\;\; v_n=v_0.q^n$$

in your case, $ v_0=3 $ and $ q=\frac 14$.

The sum of termes of $ (v_n) $ is
given by

$$S_N=v_0+v_1+v_2+...+v_N=v_0\frac{1-q^{N+1}}{1-q}$$

$$=3\frac{1-\frac{1}{4^{N+1}}}{1-\frac 14}$$

$$=4-\frac{1}{4^N}$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Helped alot